# php foreach loop not displaying second href

Tags: php, loops

I have a database query statement that runs, and using PHP I save the relevant variables to echo out in another variable like so:

```
$output = "";

$query = $DBH->query("
    SELECT bar, foo
    FROM table
    WHERE user = 2
");

foreach($query->fetchAll() as $row){
    $foo = $row['foo'];
    $bar = $row['bar'];
    $output .= "
        <a href='" .$foo. "'><p>" .$bar. "</p></a <!--i was missing a closing '>'-->
    ";
}

echo $output;
```

Now say the table is holding two rows of data both with `user = 1`, `$output` should display two elements like so:

```
<a href='foo'><p>bar</p></a>
<a href='foo'><p>bar</p></a>
```

The `<p>` tags and the `$bar` content show up fine (as in both are being echoed), however, only the first `<a>` tag is being echoed.

If I were to inspect the elements the HTML would look like this:

```
<a href='foo'><p>bar</p></a>
<p>bar</p> <!--where's the <a> tag?-->
```

Why isn't the second (or third for that matter) `<a>` tag not showing up?

**SOLVED**

Comment: What second `<a>` tag? Where it supposed to come from?

Comment: @zerkms, it's supposed to be echoed like the first. read what `$output` should be displaying

Comment: Still don't see it, sorry. I see that it outputs a `user=2`.

Comment: Try to run it on your sql and check how many results it gives

Comment: `$output .= "<a href='" .$foo. "'><p>" .$bar. "</p></a>";`

Comment: It does not explain where the second `<a>` should come from.

Comment: @zerkms, sorry, my question is not clear, editing now

Comment: I think I know what you are saying, but from what you are describing and based on your code, it should not skip other `<a>` tags.

Comment: Are you checking the output by clicking on  view page source

Comment: @Hudixt, yes, and the second and third `<a>` tags aren't showing up

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code try to check it with different browser

Comment: Embarrassing, but I was missing a closing `>` in my actual code, sorry guys, thanks for the support!